# Java Null pointers

Tags: android, inheritance

I have two classes in Android Java, with inheritance between them, I need that the value of variable in the father will be the same in the child, without any change. This is possible?

Comment: Do not declare the variable in both classes, just in the `SuperClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by following way,

```
public class classFather 
{ 
     protected static final int fatherClassVariable = 0;

     . 
     . 
     . 

}

public class childClass1 extends classFather     // make sure childClass is present in same package or package inside the father class's package.
{
      int childClassVariable = classFather.fatherClassVariable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can declare the variable in the Parent class as

```
 protected static final nameVariable;
```

this way it will be visible only to the classes that inerith from that Parent and its value can be not changed

Comment: thank you! I put that but the final produce an error, with static, i have the same situation I told in the answer

Comment: what kind of error. final requires that you initialise the variable in the constructor or at declaration time

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make much sense.
If your parent class A has a member then it will be inherited by its child classes as long as the visibility of the member is public/protected/default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable in the father class as public or protected. Then, you can access it from either class.

Comment: I have it public static and i get the same error.